# possible to output current CPU and MEM usage via ruby script ? i am trying to find memory leaks

Tags: ruby, linux

is it possible to, say, output the current consumption of CPU and memory in ruby script?

i am trying to find memory leaks in my jruby script.

CPU usage keeps going up to 100% until it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445714/how-to-profile-jruby-code doesn't look promising.  I have no idea if perftool.rb will do any better on jruby.

Answer (score 0):

the OS gem has an rss_bytes method, but that might not help with jruby.